# Unexpected result with soft shadows when rendering a beveled cube in Cycles (3.0)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, bevel, shadows

This seems like it should be pretty simple, but I must be missing or misunderstanding something.

I have a cube with a bevel modifier on it, and I want it to have pretty soft shadows.
But the result is that you can pretty much see where the beveled geometry transitions to the cubes sides...the shadows are much sharper than I expected - compared to the sphere next to it which has very soft shadows.

[image]

Thinking that it is a lack of geometry that causes this, I tried adding a subdivision surface modifier, but that made the problem even worse:

[image]

Adding more bevel segments does not seem to help either, nor does beveling manually.

I realize that comparing the shadows on the sphere with the shadows on the bevels might not be entirely fair, but it seems the transition between each individual bevel face is still softer than the transition to the flat cube face.

What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried activating automatic normals in the object properties?

Comment: If you mean Normals/Auto Smooth then yes, it doesn't seem to make any difference in this case.

Comment: Try adding some inset faces so that the smoothing isn’t trying to make the whole side of the cube appear round.

Comment: @TheLabCat Insets doesn’t seem to make any difference either…I was thinking along the same lines that it is the size difference of the faces that causes the issue. I’ll experiment some more…